# How to solve : could not load or assembly Npgsql or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-6

I am trying to create an API using C #, but as I have to enable migrations I have the following errors:

```
The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Npgsql' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.
```

I am using EntityFramework 6.2.0 and EntityFramework.Npgsql 3.2.1.1 and after inserting the following code snippet into Web.config:

```cs
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Npgsql" />
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" support="FF" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

And now I'm having this problem:

```cs
Checking if the context targets an existing database...
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Npgsql, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'Npgsql, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7' ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Npgsql, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'Npgsql, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7'

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName)
   at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(DataRow providerRow)
   at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultProviderFactoryResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key, Func`3 handleFailedLookup)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultProviderFactoryResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CachingDependencyResolver.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetService>b__0(Tuple`2 k)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CachingDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetService>b__0(IDbDependencyResolver r)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.RootDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetService>b__0(IDbDependencyResolver r)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CompositeResolver`2.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbDependencyResolverExtensions.GetService[T](IDbDependencyResolver resolver, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateConnectionFromProviderName(String providerInvariantName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings appConfigConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_Connection()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_Connection()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo..ctor(Type contextType, DbProviderInfo modelProviderInfo, AppConfig config, DbConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Func`1 resolver)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState, Boolean calledByCreateDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration migrationsConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.RunCore()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()


Could not load file or assembly 'Npgsql, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

```
Warning     Found conflicts between different versions of "Npgsql" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
```

I'm using the EntityFramework 6.2.0 and EntityFramework.Npgsql 3.2.1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instala a versão 4.1.1 do npgsql 
Install-Package Npgsql -Version 4.1.1

Answer (score 1):

Download https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/releases/download/v4.1.8/Npgsql.msi

then install.

[image]

See more at

https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/tree/v4.1.8

https://www.npgsql.org/doc/installation.html#windows-msi-installer

Comment: I couldn't find msi file for version 5.

Comment: Have change: https://www.npgsql.org/doc/installation.html#windows-msi-installer